# Huge 2d pixelized world

Tags: unity, shaders, strategy

I would like to make a game field in a indie-strategic 2d game to be some a-like this popular picture.
[image]

So every "pixel"(blocks) changes it's color slowly, sometimes a bright color wave happens, etc, but the spaces beetwen this pixels should stay dark (not to count shades, lightning and other 3rd party stuff going on). Units are going to be same "pixelized" and should position them-selfs according those blocks.

I have some experience in game-developing, but this task seems not trivial for me. What approaches (shader, tons of sprites or code-render, i don't now) would you recommend me to follow?
(I'm thinking of making this game using Unity Engine)
Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Aspcartman, your enthusiasm is good! However, [how to make an entire game](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/171/how-to-make-an-entire-game-x-off-topic) is off topic for the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask.

Comment: post processing pixel shader's the way to go.

Comment: Change colors to more of blue then black, and I have a name for your game: "Toilet wars"

Comment: @Byte56 I don't think he is asking how to make a game, but just how to make some special effect applied to my game.

Comment: All right, I suppose we'll get clarification when OP returns.

Answer (score 5):

```
float size = 1.0 / NumTiles;

float2 Base = UV - fmod(UV, size.xx);
float2 Center = Base + (size/2.0).xx;

return tex2D(ScreenTexture, Center);
```

Make your render target be a texture called ScreenTexture, render your scene, make the rendertarget be the backbuffer again, draw a fullscreen quad with ScreenTexture and apply this shader on it. It is called Post Processing Pixel Shader. Should work fine for it.

EDIT:
With in-between gaps:

```
float size = 1.0 / NumTiles;
float2 PixelSize = 1.0 / ScreenSize; //ScreenSize is a float2(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)
float2 Part = fmod(UV, size.xx)
if(any(Part < PixelSize) || any(Part > (size.xx - PixelSize))
    return float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
float2 Base = UV - Part;
float2 Center = Base + (size/2.0).xx;

return tex2D(ScreenTexture, Center);
```